# Making a geodesic polyhedron with spheres on the vertices

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, instances, wireframe

Firstly, I'm relatively new to Blender, so apologies if this is an obvious question.
Using the Ico Sphere, I've made a Geodesic Polyhedron. I've also wireframed this and made spheres appear on the edges of each of the vertices. However, since the wireframe registers multiple intersecting vertices, it generates multiple spheres on each vertex, as shown in the image. I'd like only one sphere to be present on each of the edges of the vertices as opposed to one. There must be a way around this. Thanks in advance!
[image: Polyhedron with spheres on vertices]

Comment: Create a new icosphere that you parent to this one and that will be invisible?

Comment: @moonboots, great idea should have thought of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.. you could just use a quick little GN modifier..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with geometry nodes but I will try this approach, seems like the quickest!

Answer (score 3):

Create a new icosphere that is exactly like your original one, except you don't give it thickness, enable *Instancing > Vertices*, parent the little sphere to it, make it invisible (disable the *Show Instancer* options), align it with your first icosphere and parent it to it:

[image]